# SignalR sending data from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I wanted to send the data from server side to client side using SignalR.
I have a `Task` here that iterate over the job. This job inherits `Hub` class from SignalR where it sends the current progress of the iteration. However it won't return me the data that I sent from the server side.

```
public async Task loop()
{
    ProgressHub p = new ProgressHub();

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        await p.SendProgress(i, 100);
    }
}

public async Task SendProgress(int currentRow, int rowCount)
{
   string message = "Initializing and Preparing...";
   int percent = (currentRow * 100) / rowCount;


    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
    var percentage = (currentRow * 100) / rowCount;

    hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(message, percent + "%");

    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Calling loop method on Controller.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CallSignalR()
{
    await loop();

    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Calling SignalR on JS

```
var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

console.log(progressNotifier);

progressNotifier.client.addProgress = function (currentRow, rowCount) {

console.log(currentRow);
};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

Comment: What does `console.log(currentRow)` write to the console?

Comment: @mjwills It returns nothing. But `progressNotifier` returns the properties of connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define and assign your function in a different way. For example as following:

```
var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;
console.log(progressNotifier);

progressNotifier.client.addProgress = onAddProgress;

function onAddProgress(currentRow, rowCount) {
    console.log(currentRow);
};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

I also suggest you to use a single parameter for these kind of functions, I've got some problems in the past with multiple parameters. You can pass a single Json message and deserialize it later.